# ORA-00900 sending me crazy

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, compiler-errors

Hi I have created a procedure to delete customer information from a database.
Here is the code for this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_customer (customer_id VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM order_line
    WHERE  order_line.order_id in
    (SELECT order_id FROM placed_order
     WHERE placed_order.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id
    );

    DELETE FROM placed_order
    WHERE placed_order.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;

    DELETE FROM customer
    WHERE customer.customer_id = remove_customer.customer_id;
END;
```

This is producing the ORA-00900 and i can't figure out what is wrong with the code?

Also it is producing this error.

Error at line 4: PLS-00302: component 'ORDER_ID' must be declared

anyone spot anything?

thanks

Comment: ORA-00900 means invalid SQL statement.

Comment: @RichardC - do you get the error when you compile or when you run? If you get it when you run, how are you running the procedure?

Comment: When i run it but the error has now changed to 

Error at line 4: PLS-00302: component 'ORDER_ID' must be declared?

Comment: Check your table. Does the table ORDER_LINE have a column named ORDER_ID on it?  Please note - capitalization is important here.  If there's a column which looks like ORDER_LINE, is it all upper-case, mixed case, or lower case?

Comment: think ive got it, its called fk1_order_id im guessing thats the problem

Comment: Yes that would be it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you should have used

```
customer_id
```

instead of

```
remove_customer.customer_id
```

Comment: hmm i tried changing all the remove_customer but still receiving the same error?

Comment: Your alternative of `customer_id` is legal (Oracle chooses the local parameter variable over the column name), but `remove_customer.customer_id` is also legal. I don't think it's the cause of the problem.

Comment: hmm a new error is now coming up.

Error at line 4: PLS-00302: component 'ORDER_ID' must be declared

any ideas?

Comment: Managed to get it working thanks anyway

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pls_00302.htm Looks like the problem is that Oracle can't distinguish between order_line.order_id and placed_order.order_id; please, try SELECT placed_order.order_id FROM placed_order

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE remove_customer (prm_customer_id VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM order_line
    WHERE  order_line.order_id in
    (SELECT placed_order.order_id FROM placed_order
     WHERE placed_order.customer_id = prm_customer_id
    );

    DELETE FROM placed_order
    WHERE placed_order.customer_id = prm_customer_id;

    DELETE FROM customer
    WHERE customer.customer_id = prm_customer_id;
END;

Comment: Hi @DmitryBychenko, The problem turned out to be simple in the end i was simply selecting wrong values eg customer_id should of been fk1_customer_id so it was just a mistake by me.

Thanks a lot for the help and link tho

Comment: Depending on your religion, you may want to make your foreign keys `on delete cascade` making your `remove customer` procedure trivial.